# Change encoding on the fly with jquery or php

Tags: jquery, ajax, encoding, hebrew

I have a problem with my Ajax and PHP querys involving Hebrew.

When I submit a form with a GET method on php with a Hebrew string, lets say "בית", it sends me to a page with this address: search.php?q=%E1%E9%FA.
Which pulls data from database with ease.

But with Ajax and Jquery the address looks like this: search.php?q=בית.
This result, needless to say - isn't working when trying to pull data from the data base.

What type of encoding is this %E1%E9%FA?
and is there a way of changing on the fly in PHP or Jquery?
I tried googling it for quite some time with no success.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't know what your encoding is, it's probably ANSI. ANSI means "the encoding of Windows versions sold in your country". Have a look at [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) when you have some time.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
var text = 'בית'
var textEncoded = encodeURIComponent(text)
```

and send the textEncoded as query parameter